# Electron: how to capture computer activities with electron app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, electron, keylogger

I am considering using electron to develop a desktop app that captures computer activities with Mac. I planned to use rescuetime API before, but the user research project I am working on requires more detailed computer usage data. Now I can use [global-shortcut](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/global-shortcut.md) to register some actions, But I could only run it on main process not render process.

I also wonder if I could **detect when user switch task from one application to another like switching from photoshop to chrome, closing/minimizing a window of another application, etc.?**

Does anyone have any idea on how to do it? Or is there any API/package available for that use?

(PS: robot.js seems relevant, but it is too complex and requires tons of dependencies, which is too complicated for my project.)

Comment: you can use global-shortcut on your main process and then send messages to the renderer by using BrowserWindow.webContents.send(msg)

Answer (score 3):

There's really no way to do what you're asking with electron or really any web-based application framework. You can capture keyboard input, but this:

> I wonder if I could detect when user switch task from one application to >  another like switching from photoshop to chrome, closing/minimizing a window of >another application, and pressing ctrl+s, etc.?

Implies that your app's window would not have focus during a lot of the key-presses you would have to capture. v8 and other browser based applications don't have access to the system api's that you would need to capture this info.

[What you need to use if you're on Windows.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx)

If you can't/don't want to write native code you will need to use DLLImport on user32.dll.

Comment: Surely this answer is correct, node alone could not do that, but [gkm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gkm) is probably going to get the job done